# "How to fix ' Error: Missing required flag:» -a, --app APP app to run command against' \"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cmd

I executed the follwoing command in command prompt and I have created an app on heroku yet it gives the error

`heroku run rails db:migrate`
 »   Error: Missing required flag:
 »     -a, --app APP  app to run command against
 »   See more help with --help

Tried searching heroku logs

> 2019-09-15T23:22:03.826467+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’:
>   No such file or directory 2019-09-15T23:22:03.887547+00:00
>   heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
>   2019-09-16T05:06:15.268706+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   crashed to starting 2019-09-16T05:06:19.064451+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 41217 -e
>   production` 2019-09-16T05:06:20.637179+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State
>   changed from starting to crashed 2019-09-16T05:06:20.616950+00:00
>   heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
>   2019-09-16T05:06:20.568893+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’:
>   No such file or directory 2019-09-16T10:42:34.516751+00:00
>   heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
>   2019-09-16T10:42:39.365915+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
>   command `bin/rails server -p 27735 -e production`
>   2019-09-16T10:42:41.289745+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   starting to crashed 2019-09-16T10:42:41.203395+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’: No such file or directory
>   2019-09-16T10:42:41.268687+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
>   status 127 2019-09-16T16:31:37.067690+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State
>   changed from crashed to starting 2019-09-16T16:31:41.701046+00:00
>   heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p
>   52026 -e production` 2019-09-16T16:31:43.999349+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   State changed from starting to crashed
>   2019-09-16T16:31:43.975547+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
>   status 127 2019-09-16T16:31:43.918012+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env:
>   ‘ruby\r’: No such file or directory 2019-09-16T22:39:55.908946+00:00
>   heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
>   2019-09-16T22:40:00.637605+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
>   command `bin/rails server -p 50388 -e production`
>   2019-09-16T22:40:03.584058+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
>   status 127 2019-09-16T22:40:03.629507+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State
>   changed from starting to crashed 2019-09-16T22:40:03.531525+00:00
>   app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’: No such file or directory
>   2019-09-17T04:24:15.379655+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   crashed to starting 2019-09-17T04:24:21.321402+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 14027 -e
>   production` 2019-09-17T04:24:24.253848+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State
>   changed from starting to crashed 2019-09-17T04:24:24.230953+00:00
>   heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
>   2019-09-17T04:24:24.154928+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’:
>   No such file or directory 2019-09-17T09:52:33.650300+00:00
>   heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
>   2019-09-17T09:52:39.146334+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
>   command `bin/rails server -p 40826 -e production`
>   2019-09-17T09:52:41.001113+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   starting to crashed 2019-09-17T09:52:40.924938+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’: No such file or directory
>   2019-09-17T09:52:40.984194+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
>   status 127 2019-09-17T15:28:48.778454+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State
>   changed from crashed to starting 2019-09-17T15:28:53.307226+00:00
>   heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p
>   16148 -e production` 2019-09-17T15:28:55.359519+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   State changed from starting to crashed
>   2019-09-17T15:28:55.243938+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’:
>   No such file or directory 2019-09-17T15:28:55.336119+00:00
>   heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
>   2019-09-17T21:13:21.875113+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   crashed to starting 2019-09-17T21:13:25.856657+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 28944 -e
>   production` 2019-09-17T21:13:27.520323+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process
>   exited with status 127 2019-09-17T21:13:27.550439+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   State changed from starting to crashed
>   2019-09-17T21:13:27.461219+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’:
>   No such file or directory 2019-09-18T02:41:53.865983+00:00
>   heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
>   2019-09-18T02:41:57.945944+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
>   command `bin/rails server -p 7314 -e production`
>   2019-09-18T02:41:59.795897+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   starting to crashed 2019-09-18T02:41:59.777871+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   Process exited with status 127 2019-09-18T02:41:59.722045+00:00
>   app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’: No such file or directory
>   2019-09-18T08:26:23.419922+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   crashed to starting 2019-09-18T08:26:27.839432+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 32803 -e
>   production` 2019-09-18T08:26:29.966449+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State
>   changed from starting to crashed 2019-09-18T08:26:29.946075+00:00
>   heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
>   2019-09-18T08:26:29.888263+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’:
>   No such file or directory 2019-09-18T14:08:33.941110+00:00
>   heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
>   2019-09-18T14:08:39.752110+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
>   command `bin/rails server -p 33709 -e production`
>   2019-09-18T14:08:42.155656+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
>   status 127 2019-09-18T14:08:42.180081+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State
>   changed from starting to crashed 2019-09-18T14:08:42.083565+00:00
>   app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’: No such file or directory
>   2019-09-18T19:52:46.120013+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   crashed to starting 2019-09-18T19:52:51.295227+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 44938 -e
>   production` 2019-09-18T19:52:53.197924+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process
>   exited with status 127 2019-09-18T19:52:53.223854+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   State changed from starting to crashed
>   2019-09-18T19:52:53.153572+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’:
>   No such file or directory 2019-09-19T01:37:00.215362+00:00
>   heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
>   2019-09-19T01:37:04.477733+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
>   command `bin/rails server -p 36294 -e production`
>   2019-09-19T01:37:06.410727+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   starting to crashed 2019-09-19T01:37:06.384642+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   Process exited with status 127 2019-09-19T01:37:06.338693+00:00
>   app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’: No such file or directory
>   2019-09-19T07:05:16.770576+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   crashed to starting 2019-09-19T07:05:22.844128+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 38345 -e
>   production` 2019-09-19T07:05:25.392706+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State
>   changed from starting to crashed 2019-09-19T07:05:25.384920+00:00
>   heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
>   2019-09-19T07:05:25.252421+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’:
>   No such file or directory 2019-09-19T12:33:28.513468+00:00
>   heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
>   2019-09-19T12:33:33.743057+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
>   command `bin/rails server -p 24113 -e production`
>   2019-09-19T12:33:35.821273+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   starting to crashed 2019-09-19T12:33:35.799108+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   Process exited with status 127 2019-09-19T12:33:35.745527+00:00
>   app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’: No such file or directory
>   2019-09-19T18:31:56.491288+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   crashed to starting 2019-09-19T18:32:00.917984+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 22360 -e
>   production` 2019-09-19T18:32:02.979933+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State
>   changed from starting to crashed 2019-09-19T18:32:02.963473+00:00
>   heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
>   2019-09-19T18:32:02.905584+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’:
>   No such file or directory 2019-09-24T22:55:14.433365+00:00
>   heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET
>   path="/" host=obscure-beyond-78036.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=aad7201f-8b7a-42d5-9f1f-dfabe3d7b2bc fwd="73.244.194.180"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
>   2019-09-24T22:55:14.980672+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
>   host=obscure-beyond-78036.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=5d588f9a-8b14-4c50-8dd1-4734babae336 fwd="73.244.194.180"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
>   2019-09-24T22:55:31.161613+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
>   host=obscure-beyond-78036.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=6b17807b-e293-4521-9e18-730a6acd7395 fwd="73.244.194.180"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
>   2019-09-24T22:55:31.565400+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
>   host=obscure-beyond-78036.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=cb6c9550-5965-4f5a-8d57-521e1ffe2ccd fwd="73.244.194.180"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
>   2019-09-26T22:38:07.431227+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with
>   command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by user saish.bhende24@gmail.com
>   2019-09-26T22:38:11.376886+00:00 heroku[run.2367]: Awaiting client
>   2019-09-26T22:38:11.422621+00:00 heroku[run.2367]: Starting process
>   with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
>   2019-09-26T22:38:11.634191+00:00 heroku[run.2367]: State changed from
>   starting to up 2019-09-26T22:38:18.247732+00:00 heroku[run.2367]:
>   State changed from up to complete 2019-09-26T22:38:18.228431+00:00
>   heroku[run.2367]: Process exited with status 0
>   2019-09-26T22:41:22.541036+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
>   host=obscure-beyond-78036.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=f0ceea6e-7734-488c-ad3f-e9b01d11c84a fwd="73.244.194.180"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
>   2019-09-26T22:41:24.051526+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
>   host=obscure-beyond-78036.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=13e5ea81-b82d-4273-93b8-0128a9d4b0e1 fwd="73.244.194.180"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
>   2019-09-26T22:43:19.102809+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
>   host=obscure-beyond-78036.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=02d99fa9-ba19-4610-a48b-053f4a202ecc fwd="73.244.194.180"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>   2019-09-26T22:59:54.566572+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
>   host=obscure-beyond-78036.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=9f527c7d-a86f-47df-95a5-f4ea9bac479d fwd="73.244.194.180"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
>   2019-09-26T22:59:55.104178+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
>   host=obscure-beyond-78036.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=56c6c1b2-36ef-43c6-92f6-a44371ba8deb fwd="73.244.194.180"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
>   2019-09-26T23:02:05.203583+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
>   host=obscure-beyond-78036.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=8d0e9e5a-a6d3-49f5-83b2-bfb260c2b143 fwd="54.198.238.84"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
>   2019-09-27T00:20:20.590533+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
>   host=obscure-beyond-78036.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=3bc112eb-37b7-4138-b163-c767b275daf3 fwd="73.244.194.180"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
>   2019-09-27T00:20:21.091296+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
>   host=obscure-beyond-78036.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=f4968a6d-6838-4d21-b4e0-9ff361b6f18d fwd="73.244.194.180"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http

`heroku run rails db:migrate`
 »   Error: Missing required flag:
 »     -a, --app APP  app to run command against
 »   See more help with --help

Expecting the code to be deployed to heroku to run the app.

Comment: @muistooshort this works thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this command to migrate

heroku run rake db:migrate --app your_app_name

or

heroku git:remote --app YOUR_APP_NAME --remote environment_name (Like test, development, production)